# Unable to get arcade controls passed as keystrokes to PiPlay

Tags: raspbian, gpio, input-device

I'm pretty new to the Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to get arcade controls
I've made working with **PiPlay** using the **Adafruit** software.

I've tested the controls with a little Python 3 program I wrote and the 4 joystick directions and 4 buttons all work as expected when the GPIO ports are pulled high.

My Raspbian version is Wheezy 7.8

I've run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and updated the software.

I've installed the programs and libraries to recompile the Adafruit software using

`sudo apt-get install git libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libncurses5 libncurses5.dev`

When I run this command again the OS reports I have the latest versions of all 5 components.

I've installed the Adafruit retrogame software and edited the `retrogame.c` to match the ports I've used and recompiled the software using the make command without errors.

I've added the udev rule to ensure compatibility with the SDL2 library.
I've added a line to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-retrogame.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="retrogame", ENV{ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD}="1"
```

I tried to make sure the retrogame program starts as soon as the OS boots by adding the following line just before the `exit 0` line of `/etc/rc.local`

```
/home/pi/Adafruit-Retrogame/retrogame &
```

I rebooted after all this. Everything seems to run fine, PiPlay loads and my ROMS play, but it looks like the joystick and button inputs are not being passed through to PiPlay from the Adafruit software.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions at this stage but I was wondering in particular the follwing.

1. Is there a way to check that the Adafruit retrogame software is up and running?
2. Is there a program I can use to check retrogame is generating keystrokes?

Comment: I discovered Adafruit has installed to a different path and the joystick now works in the PiPlay menu where I have configured the controller using the <tab> key. The joystick still doesn't work in the ROMs though, even if I configure the joystick separately there. Help still appreciated.